# Sound issue with Pulseeffects and VLC

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, vlc

I installed `pulseeffects` recently in order to use its equalizer.

It works ok except for one thing. Sometimes, when I start an audio file (by pressing **play** on `vlc` for example) for the first time, the sound starts and stops a couple of times on each stereo channel, and then it continues playing ok. If I press **Stop** to stop the playback and start the file again, everything works correctly.

Does anyone know why this happens and how it can be stopped so that media files play correctly from the first time?

Thank you!

***Update 1***
It looks like this problem appears when using **vlc** only. Audio coming from **mpv** or **Chrome** sounds OK from the first time.

I tried changing ***automatic*** to ***pulseaudio*** on the output module setting on `vlc` to no avail. Any ideas please?